# curb gem doesn't like existing osx curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was having an issue trying to start a ruby 2.3.1 rails 4.2.8 application with `bundle exec rails s` where i was getting:

`` activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': dlopen(.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curb-0.8.8/lib/curb_core.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurl.4.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curb-0.8.8/lib/curb_core.bundle ``

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the provided gem through bundle install was originally compiled against a newer version of curl than the one that comes with OSX.

One possible solution would be to install a newer version of curl using brew `brew install curl` and then link it as the system default `brew link curl` however that would replace the default OSX curl with the newer one and could cause system problems (or other compiled software could be expecting the default osx version of the libraries)

So the best solution is to install curl with brew without linking it `brew install curl` and then reinstall curb gem linking it to the brew curl libraries:

`gem install curb -v 0.8.8 -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include`

This approach worked fine for me and I decided to include it here to save time in case anyone else comes across the same issue I had

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well because `which curl` returned `/opt/anaconda3/bin/curl`.

To fix this, I ran

```
conda remove curl
```

Then I could

```
gem install curb
```